# Trouble Retrieving Thumbnail URL on Front-Page

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails, frontpage, images

I'm running multiple queries on a `front-page.php` file. They all seem to be working fine, except that I am having a hard time getting a thumbnail image.

The code in question, on my front-page, currently looks like this:

```
<?php 

    $thumb_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'cat'            => 87
    );

    $thumb_query = new WP_Query( $thumb_args );

    while ($thumb_query->have_posts()) : $thumb_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('cat-excerpt right') ?> itemprop="blogPost">

         <h2 class="headline" itemprop="title">Posted Without Comment</h2>

         <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>

         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" itemprop="url">
              <img src="<?php get_the_post_thumbnail('custom-medium'); ?>" itemprop="image">
         </a>
    </div><!-- End .post .cat-excerpt -->
    <?php endwhile; 

        wp_reset_postdata(); 
    ?>
```

I have tried using both `the_post_thumbnail()` on its own and `get_the_post_thumbnail()` in an `<img>` tag. When I use `the_post_thumbnail()` (with or without passing an argument) it just returns an empty anchor tag, which links to the correct post. When I use `get_the_post_thumbnail()` in an `<img>` tag (with or without passing an argument, as seen above), I doesn't return the url for the image. The url for the actual post is always correct.

This is the code in my `functions.php` file:

```
if (function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array('audio','gallery', 'image', 'video'));
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    if (function_exists( 'set_post_thumbnail_size' ) ) {
        set_post_thumbnail_size( 620, 349, false );
    }
}

if (function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size( 'profile', 100, 100, false );
    add_image_size( 'custom-small', 300, 169, false );
    add_image_size( 'custom-medium', 400, 225, false );
    add_image_size( 'custom-full', 520, 293, false );
}
```

The thumbnail image works fine in my `single.php` file, which uses the default post thumbnail size that I defined above. So, if anything, I figure the issue is with the image sizes that I've added, and/or with my `front-page.php` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you do it in your `single.php`, but I'm fairly certain not the same way. The main problem is that both [`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) and [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) are generating the `img` tag output for you - so putting it into the `src` attribute of an `img` tag like in your code can't work.

Additionally: The latter does `return`, the former does `echo` the output. You are using the latter, but don't echo it so there is actually nothing happening. There are some other differences, e.g. [`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) can only be used for the current post as it has no `$post_id` parameter; [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) can be used for any post thumbnail, given you input the `$post_id`. More on the codex pages.

So the usage in your case would look like this:

```
// either:
the_post_thumbnail( 'custom-medium' );
// or:
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'custom-medium' );
```

Or if you actually want to fill the `src` attribute of an `img` tag you can do:

```
<?php
$img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(
    get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ),
    'custom-medium'
);
?>
<img src="<?php echo $img_url[0]; ?>">
```

Making use of [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src), [`get_post_thumbnail_id()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id) and [`get_the_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) - the latter was already in use in above exemplary code.

---

**Update:**

Just to clarify, above mentioned methods do *all* work - tested and used many times. I assume there must be another problem, but actually can't tell from the information available.

As proof of concept here a `front-page.php` with **custom query**:

```
<?php
get_header();

$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$thumb_args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 1,
'cat'            => 87,
'paged'          => $paged
);

$thumb_query = new WP_Query( $thumb_args );

$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $thumb_query;

if (
    $thumb_query->have_posts()
) {
    while (
        $thumb_query->have_posts()
    ) {
        $thumb_query->the_post();
            the_title();
            echo '<br>';
            the_post_thumbnail();
            echo '<br>';
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail();
            echo '<br>';
            $img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(
                get_post_thumbnail_id()
            );
            echo '<img src="'. $img_url[0]. '">';
    }
} else {
    // no posts
}

echo '<br>';
previous_posts_link( '← ' );
next_posts_link( ' →', $thumb_query->max_num_pages );

wp_reset_postdata();

$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $temp_query;

get_footer();
```

I additionally had to throw this into the `functions.php` to make the pagination work:

```
add_action(
    'pre_get_posts',
    'wpse162764_frontpage_custom_query_additional_pagination_fix'
);
function wpse162764_frontpage_custom_query_additional_pagination_fix( $query ) {
    if ( 
        is_admin()
    ) {
        return;
    }
    if (
        is_front_page()
    ) {
        $query->set(
            'posts_per_page',
            1
        );
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work for you, make sure you set the right parameter, than there *must* be another problem.

Besides, *custom queries* are *barely needed* so lets use the *main query*.

A `front-page.php` with **main query**:

```
<?php
get_header();

if (
    have_posts()
) {
    while (
        have_posts()
    ) {
        the_post();
            the_title();
            echo '<br>';
            the_post_thumbnail();
            echo '<br>';
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail();
            echo '<br>';
            $img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(
                get_post_thumbnail_id()
            );
            echo '<img src="'. $img_url[0]. '">';
    }
} else {
    // no posts
}

echo '<br>';
previous_posts_link( '← ' );
next_posts_link( ' →' );

get_footer();
```

Additionally you need this in your `functions.php` to make it work with the main query:

```
add_action(
    'pre_get_posts',
    'wpse162764_pre_get_posts_for_frontpage_main_query'
);
function wpse162764_pre_get_posts_for_frontpage_main_query( $query ) {
    if ( 
        is_admin()
        || ! $query->is_main_query()
    ) {
        return;
    }
    if (
        is_front_page()
    ) {
        $query->set(
            'posts_per_page',
            1
        );
        $query->set(
            'cat',
            87
        ); 
    }
}
```

---

*Note:*

BTW just to clarify I've ran this with multiple queries/loops too, does work and - if done right - can't be the issue.

Comment: I did not use 'the_post_thumbnail()' in an image tag, and I did mean echo, not return. Apologies for the confusion. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: No problem whatsoever, I was merely trying to say, the code I see can't work. Sure, try away :) @Codette

Comment: Got ya. :) I'd originally used 'the_post_thumbnail' once on its own, and once with the argument, and neither worked. Unfortunately, the solutions you suggested aren't working out, either. I can't even get the url.

Comment: My bad, `wp_get_attachment_image_src` does return an array, index `0` contains the URL - fixed the answer. Additionally, if you use the `get_the_post_thumbnail()` and provide the ID of an post with a post thumbnail, it's nearly impossible to not get anything. The same is actually true for `the_post_thumbnail()` if used inside the loop it - for me at least - does just always work. So I'm kind of have not the slightest idea for now what the reason could be. @Codette

Comment: Okay, I've revised my code again using your first suggestion, and everything seems fine now. I'm really not quite sure what the problem was (maybe a typo?), but thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: My pleasure. I don't know, maybe a typo, maybe I missed something in the code you posted or it was something in the code didn't see - anyhow, it works now :) @Codette

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to take it for granted that a thumbnail actually exists for any post that your query retrieves.  I would personally recommend checking for the existence of a featured image before attempting to retrieve it.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" itemprop="url">
     <img src="<?php get_the_post_thumbnail('custom-medium'); ?>" itemprop="image">
</a>
```

The method [has_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail), if executed within a loop, will tell you whether or not the current post has a thumbnail.  I would adjust your code with this in mind, and envision something along the lines of:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" itemprop="url">
    <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
    <img src="<?php get_the_post_thumbnail('custom-medium'); ?>" itemprop="image">
    <?php else: ?>
    <!-- No Image Available; maybe put something else in its place? -->
    <?php endif; ?>
</a>
```

Doing this, you can not only be sure that images are rendered only when appropriate, but also be able to identify the fact that no featured image is present for the given post (by viewing source and locating the HTML comment in my provided example).

Comment: You're right about it being a good thing to implement the check, but it's likely not addressing the problem and using `get_the_post_thumbnail()` like this just won't work.